# R - replace: how to make changes verbose, i.e. "X replacements were made"

Tags: r

In R when you make a replace I would like a fast way to check that my expectations were satisfied, for example:

```
data("mpg")
hist(mpg$cyl)
```

So only a few cars have 5 cylinders, in fact `count(mpg[mpg$cyl == 5,])` will get you the exact amount, 4. I want only 3 categories so I will `replace` 5 with 4:

```
cyl2 <- replace(mpg$cyl, mpg$cyl == 5, 4)
```

In this case checking that the desired changes took place is quite easy just type `hist(cyl2)` and you get your answer; but, in some more complex scenarios I would like to have a short statement like "X replacements were made" or something like that, just to check that my expectations were satisfied, in this case I expected 4 replacements.

Is there an easy way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write your own function; I find myself doing this often to add simple functionalities to existing functions, e.g.:

```
replace2<-function(x,list,values){
  cat(if(is.logical(list)) sum(list) else length(list))
  cat(" replacements made\n")
  replace(x,list,values)
}

cyl12<-replace2(mpg$cyl, mpg$cyl == 5, 4))
```

Examples:

```
x<-1:20
> replace2(x,x%%2==0,0)
10 replacements made
 [1]  1  0  3  0  5  0  7  0  9  0 11  0 13  0 15  0 17  0 19  0

> replace2(x,seq(1,20,by=4),0)
5 replacements made
 [1]  0  2  3  4  0  6  7  8  0 10 11 12  0 14 15 16  0 18 19 20

y<-replace2(x,x%%3==0,0)
> y
 [1]  1  2  0  4  5  0  7  8  0 10 11  0 13 14  0 16 17  0 19 20
```

---

## Edit

I'll leave this as is because the approach above is close to the general approach to such a problem, but after reading the source code for `replace`, it doesn't make any sense to call replace, as the function itself is only two lines long, so for this case in particular, I'd recommend:

```
replace2<-function(x,list,values){
  cat(if(is.logical(list)) sum(list) else length(list))
  cat(" replacements made\n")
  x[list]<-values
  x
}
```

Comment: The gist of creating your own function wrapper is, of course, correct. In this case you'd need to take extra care of the type of the second argument as it can also be specific numerical indices rather than logicals.

Comment: @A.Webb thanks, I've never actually used this function so I'm not sure all its uses. I'll edit something in for that; the caveat is a cogent one--if you're writing your own functions, always be careful that you know every sort of input that you might encounter.

Comment: I think doing `ind<-vector(length=length(x)); ind[list]<-TRUE; sum(ind)` in the body of the wrapper would be one way to cover the different indexing cases.

Comment: @A.Webb are there any cases that aren't covered by the current version? I'm not an expert on this sort of thing, but aren't the only two possibilities for index vectors `logical` or `integer`?

Comment: Thanks MichaelChirico, the custom replace2 function works like a charm in my data.